# Parsing a log file to count how many error and info entries a particular user has utilizing Python 3

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, parsing

I have the task of taking/parsing a log entry and having to first check if a regex pattern matches the `INFO` or `ERROR` message formats. Upon a successful match, add one to the corresponding value in the per_user dictionary such that if `Bob` had 3 entries in the log file and 2 were `Errors` it would generate `Bob 2 Errors 1 Info` in the dictionary. If you get an `ERROR` message, add one to the corresponding entry in the error dictionary by using proper data structure.

The logfiles are of the following layout:

```
Jan 31 00:21:30 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: The ticket was modified while updating (breee)
```

I've been trying out whether to use Collections module or not and whether it would be best to use findall or .search.  Here is what I've got so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import operator
import re
from collections import defaultdict

errors = defaultdict(int)
per_user = defaultdict(list)

file = open("syslog.log")
error_count = 0

for line in file:
  #Set regular expression to find lines containing INFO or Error followed by colon the log message as an option and the username in parentheses at the end of the line... Contains 3 groups)
  info = re.findall(r"ticky: (?P<logtype>INFO|ERROR): (?P<logmessage>[\w].*)? \((?P<username>[\w]*)\)$", line, re.MULTILINE)

  for logtype, logmessage, username in info:


    per_user[username].append(logtype)


file.close()
print(per_user)
```

This returns the info as `{username: [logtype(s)]}` and I'm not sure if I can take that information and run a count on it OR if it would be better to scrap the current code and do a `.search()` or `. match()` with an if statement and counter.

These dictionaries will be written to CSV files if that makes a difference.

Comment: What would be the structure of your desired dictionary?

Comment: I may be thinking about it wrong as I'll need to write the dictionary out to a CSV where I can create its headers regardless of the keys right?  I am trying to understand how I can count the number of entry types per user.. I want to to look like {Bob: [Errors:2 Info:1]}  or something to that effect.   So that when I convert to CSV with DictWriter   The headings would be username, error, info  and the rows would be <username>, # of errors, # of info   entries.

Comment: you should use nested dictionary instead of nested list - dictionary `{"error": ..., "info": ...}` inside dictionary `{"bob":  ...}`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have 50 reputation to comment in your post. So, here is a "attempt" to answer your question. Feel free to comment and mark if this solves your question.

Take a look at the code:

```py
import csv
import re

per_user = {}

file = open("syslog.log")

for line in file:
    #Set regular expression to find lines containing INFO or Error followed by colon the log message as an option and the username in parentheses at the end of the line... Contains 3 groups)
    info = re.findall(r"ticky: (?P<logtype>INFO|ERROR): (?P<logmessage>[\w].*)? \((?P<username>[\w]*)\)$", line, re.MULTILINE)
    for logtype, logmessage, username in info:
        if username not in per_user:
            per_user[username] = {
                "username": username,
                "INFO": 0,
                "ERROR": 0
            } # Creates a new dict for that user

        per_user[username][logtype] += 1 # Sum one to INFO or ERROR counters

file.close()

for user_data in per_user.values():
    print(user_data) # TODO: This is only for debugging
```

Notes:

- if username does not exist in the current dictionary, it instance a new dictionary for that user and also initializes it with 3 keys: username, INFO, ERROR (last 2 are the counters)
- then tries to sum up 1 to the current logtype
- per_user.values() search for the values of each user (which are dictionaries)

I've made a log file with 3 entries, with the same format as your question posts:

```
Jan 31 00:21:30 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: The ticket was modified while updating (breee)
Jan 31 00:21:30 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: The ticket was modified while updating (sam)
Jan 31 00:21:30 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO: The ticket was successful (breee)
```

And the output of the script is:

```
{'username': 'breee', 'INFO': 1, 'ERROR': 1}
{'username': 'sam', 'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 1}
```

This will become handy when using DictWriter of the csv module.

---

Note aside. You can use the context manager called "with" to open the log file.

```
...
with open("syslog.log", 'r') as file:
  for line in file:
    #Set...
    info = re.findall(...
...
```

With this, you can safely omit closing the file.

---

CSV Module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

DictWriter Method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

See the example code of the python documentation:

```py
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

For your case:

```py
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['username', 'INFO', 'ERROR']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader() # Writes the field names
    for user_data in per_user.values():
      writer.writerow(user_data)
```

Output in the file 'output.csv':

```
username,INFO,ERROR
breee,1,1
sam,0,1
```

---

You can adapt this code to your needs.

Best regards,
Goran

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'll give this a try as well.  I know Python says there should be only one acceptable way to do something, and I am still learning so may not quite understand which way is better both in output and clean code.. but also in efficiency.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm learning also. If you want to get the basics [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) has a really simple tutorial. I saw that you imported a "defaultdict" from "collections", I haven't saw that before. It was interesting to know that it exists. But you can consider to use the builtin data types.

Comment: I looked through geek for geeks and realpython.com beyond the book(s) I have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested dictionary to create structure

```
{
    "bob":    {"error": ..., "info": ...},
    "breee":  {"error": ..., "info": ...},
}
```

And you can do it with nested `defaultdict`

```
def errors():
    return defaultdict(int)

per_user = defaultdict(errors)
```

or using `lambda`

```
per_user = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))
```

(`defaultdict` needs function's name (without `()`) so it can't be `defaultdict(defaultdict(int))`)

And now you can count it

```
for logtype, logmessage, username in info:
    per_user[username][logtype] += 1
```

After counting you can display it.

Because some users may not have some messages in log (and in `per_user`) so you have to use `logtype.get('ERROR', 0)` instead of `logtype['ERROR']`

```
for user, logtype in per_user.items():
    error = logtype.get('ERROR', 0)
    info  = logtype.get('INFO', 0)         
    print(user, error, 'errors',  info, 'infos')
```

And the same way you can save in `CSV`

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    # write header
    csvwriter.writerow(['name', 'error', 'info'])
    
    # write rows
    for user, logtype in per_user.items():
        error = logtype.get('ERROR', 0)
        info  = logtype.get('INFO', 0)         
        print(user, error, 'errors',  info, 'infos')
        csvwriter.writerow([user, error, info])
```

---

Minimal working example. I used list `file` instead of real data from file so everyone can run it without problems. But you can use `open()`, `close()`

```
import csv
import re
from collections import defaultdict

per_user = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))

#file = open("syslog.log")

file = [
    'Jan 31 00:21:30 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: The ticket was modified while updating (breee)',
    'Jan 31 00:21:30 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO: hello world (bob)',
]

for line in file:
    #Set regular expression to find lines containing INFO or Error followed by colon the log message as an option and the username in parentheses at the end of the line... Contains 3 groups)
    info = re.findall(r"ticky: (?P<logtype>INFO|ERROR): (?P<logmessage>[\w].*)? \((?P<username>[\w]*)\)$", line, re.MULTILINE)

    for logtype, logmessage, username in info:
        per_user[username][logtype] += 1

#file.close()
print(per_user)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    # write header
    csvwriter.writerow(['name', 'error', 'info'])
    
    # write rows
    for user, logtype in per_user.items():
        error = logtype.get('ERROR', 0)
        info  = logtype.get('INFO', 0)         
        print(user, error, 'errors',  info, 'infos')
        csvwriter.writerow([user, error, info])
```

Comment: Thank you for that example.  Should it not be, for me, csv.dictwriter as I'm taking it from dicitonary data type and converting to csv with header and rows?    Yes, I am still learning how match(), search() and findall() operate and wasn't sure how to get put it in the format needed.

Comment: maybe you could use `csv.dictwriter` for this. Mostly I have rows as list so I almost never need use `csv.dictwriter` :)

Comment: I should have said that the errors will need to be tabulated as well based on how often an error message occurs and I'm not sure I can do that based on having errors moved into a function.

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page - and you will have more space to better describe problem, show expected result, etc.

Comment: where tabulated - on screen ? how tablulated ? You would have to show it in new question. Mayb you need only string formatting - see [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/). If you need change order then maybe you have to sort them - but this you have to do after you get all data from log.